# Understand :[] use in rpec test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I decided to take a swing at updating some ruby code for an open source project. Its a stretch because my Ruby experience is nil but I am getting there. Issue I am running into is understanding a line in an rspec test.

Section under test is below. Based on what I understand options is a variable on the class or what is passed in by default to ruby methods.

```
def handler
    module_name = options[:module_name] || default_module_name
    handler_name = option(:handler_name)

    "#{module_name}.#{handler_name}"
  end
```

Test was

```
expect(provider.options).to receive(:[]).with(:module_name).and_return(nil)
```

I am trying to access a `:runtime` key on a hash so I updated like this:

```
def handler
    module_name = options[:module_name] || default_module_name
    runtime = options[:runtime] || default_runtime
    handler_name = option(:handler_name)

    "#{module_name}.#{handler_name}"
  end
```

Updated test

```
expect(provider.options).to receive(:[]).with(:module_name, :runtime).and_return(nil)
```

My interpretation of `to receive(:[]).with(:module_name, :runtime)` is take an array object / method(?) and put the values `:module_name, :runtime` in it.

However, this is clearly not correct because the test fails with:

```
received :[] with unexpected arguments expected: (:module_name, :runtime) got: (:module_name)
```

So what is `:[]` and how can it be updated to take 2 arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:[]` is a method that implements indexing operator in your case e.gg `options[:module_name]`.

[See docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)

```
[1] pry(main)> h = {a: 1, b: 2}
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
[2] pry(main)> h[:a]
=> 1
[3] pry(main)> h.send(:[], :a)
=> 1
[4] pry(main)>
```

If you want to stub it for multiple calls, use multiple expectations:

```
expect(provider.options).to receive(:[]).with(:module_name).and_return(nil)
expect(provider.options).to receive(:[]).with(:runtime).and_return(nil)
```

https://makandracards.com/makandra/51337-rspec-expecting-multiple-calls-of-the-same-method

Answer (score 3):

`:[]` here is a hash accessor, it *should* accept a single argument (the hash key to access).

IMO this test makes no sense.

You should be testing the return value of `handler`: *how* `handler` creates that value is an internal implementation detail.

If you *explicitly* need to know that it's accessing the correct `option` entries then test that it accesses *both* `options[:module_name]` and `options[:runtime]`. But this would be tested by checking the return value of `handler` and proper test setup.

Comment: So then what that section of respc is saying is call the hash accessory method looking for a key just splitting it out?

Comment: @nerdlyist I'm not sure what you're asking. The original test ensures `provider.options` receives a `:[]` call with the `:module_name` symbol as its parameter. Your test wants to ensure it receives multiple `:[]` calls, once with `:module_name` and once with `:runtime`.

Comment: @nerdlyist (With the caveat that I'm not convinced that the testing of internal implementation is a good idea, because ultimately what is being cared about here is the return value of `handler`.)

Comment: This answer helped me understand what `:[]` was doing I did not realize it was the accessor method for the hash class. Googling those characters does not yield good results.

Comment: Also there is further test that get to testing the implementation of handler the expectation is that a handler_name must be present or else nil is returned.

Comment: @nerdlyist When you see `to receive` it means you're expecting a method call. The expected method will be a symbol, which is what the `:` turns things into.